# How to create div and assign object to dataset dynamically using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have below div (class name 'sp') which I would like to dynamically create based on the sk from a dataset object.

**div code**

```
<div style="" class="swindow">
     <div class="sp" style="">
        <div class="svis" style="">
             <div style="height:95%;width:95%;margin-top:0px;margin-left:5px;">
                <chart dsn="dyndata" editable="false" labelled="true"></chart>
             </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="sdata" style="">
            <div class="stext" style="">Average:78% </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

While searching for similar examples, I came across ng-repeat in Angular js and I thought it might suit for this kind of objective.
But am very new to Angular js and not sure how to assign the data to my dyndata variable dynamically and create new div (class=sp) for each of the given id.

Here is the lookup object

```
[
{"id":20,"st":[{"label":"Audi","value":10},{"label":"BMW","value":70}]},
{"id":26,"st":[{"label":"Benz","value":40},{"label":"BMW","value":20}]},
{"id":12,"st":[{"label":"AUDI","value":60},{"label":"Tesla","value":70}]},
{"id":57,"st":[{"label":"MZ","value":30},{"label":"Honda","value":40}]}
]
```

When I input the id's as a set [12,26,57] - Three divs (each for #sp) should get created one for each of ids. In those, each div should have the dyndata assigned with the respective 'st' from above javascript object.

I could create div's in jquery using .append function to the container (#swindow) each time when I need. But am not sure how to assign sk as input to dyndata dataset for each div that gets created.

Could you please share how this can be achieved using Angular js ?

Here is the angular js code I used -

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ui.plot']);
    app.controller('PlotCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dyndata={};
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but I think it should look something like this. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mj38eLELojjGwezzUk7o) is a plnkr..

Controller:

```
app.controller('PlotCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.items = [
  {"id":20,"st":[{"label":"Audi","value":10},{"label":"BMW","value":70}]},
  {"id":26,"st":[{"label":"Benz","value":40},{"label":"BMW","value":20}]},
  {"id":12,"st":[{"label":"AUDI","value":60},{"label":"Tesla","value":70}]},
  {"id":57,"st":[{"label":"MZ","value":30},{"label":"Honda","value":40}]}
 ]


});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="PlotCtrl">
 <div style="" class="swindow">
   <div class="sp" style="" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="svis" style="">
        <strong>{{item.id}}:</strong>
        <div>-{{item.st[0].label}}</div>
        <div>-{{item.st[1].label}}</div>
           <div style="height:95%;width:95%;margin-top:0px;margin-left:5px;">
              <chart dsn="dyndata" editable="false" labelled="true"></chart>
           </div>                
      </div>
      <div class="sdata" style="">
          <div class="stext" style="">Average:78% </div>
          <br>
      </div> 
    </div>  
 </div>  
</body>
```